# Best way to smooth overlapping images after stitching them together?

Tags: python, opencv

We create a 360 degree photo of the sky from many camera photos from different angles. During this process, few imperfections arise:

[image: Close up of sky stitch]

What would be the best way to get rid of of these visible overlaps? Is it possible to do after the stitching or should we try to prevent this during the process of stitching?

We already tried blurring the lines after the stitch but it does not seem to be the right way to go.

```
img = cv2.imread('light-sky-stitch-202001011200.png')
blurred_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (211, 211), 0)

mask = np.zeros((2000, 2000, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.circle(img=mask, center=(1000, 1000), radius=500, 
                  color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=-1)

out = np.where(mask==np.array([255, 255, 255]), blurred_img, img)
```

Comment: Gradient blending. But it is not trivial. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444510/creating-a-linear-gradient-mask-using-opencv-or/58459999#58459999

Comment: Will check that out, thank you very much :)