# Warp Prespective of opencv not giving accurate result

Tags: python, opencv, image-stitching

I want to stitch two images having a partial overlapping region to do this I am using OpenCV. After matching of keypoints using orb and flann and finding the homography, I performed a warp perspective, but I don't get the required result. I don't understand what I am doing wrong I am very new to this please help.
I am attaching the code

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def rotated(img):
   (h,w)=img.shape[:2]
   center=(w / 2,h / 2)
   m=cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center,359.5,1)
   rotate=cv2.warpAffine(img,m,(w,h))
   plt.imshow(rotate)
   plt.show()
   return rotate



d=(600,400)
img2= cv2.imread('G:/mca6thsem/bulletsimages/a31/a22/5500k/land2_part1.jpeg')
img1 = cv2.imread('G:/mca6thsem/bulletsimages/a31/a22/5500k/land2prt2.jpeg')
img1=cv2.resize(img1,d)
img1=rotated(img1)
img2=cv2.resize(img2,d)
img2=rotated(img2)
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
kp, des= orb.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2, None)




imgor = cv2.drawKeypoints(img1,kp,None,color=(0,255,0))
imgor1 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img2,kp1,None,color=(0,255,0))
#flann
FLANN_INDEX_LSH=0
index_params= dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_LSH,
                   table_number = 6, # 12
                   key_size = 12,     # 20
                   multi_probe_level = 1) #2
search_params = dict(checks=30)
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(np.float32(des),np.float32(des1),k=2)



good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.9*n.distance:
        good.append(m)

if len(good)>10:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kp[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
    h = img1.shape[1]
    w= img1.shape[0]




dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img2,M,(img2.shape[1] + img1.shape[1], img2.shape[0]))
dst[0:img1.shape[0],0:img1.shape[1]]=img1

draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0), # draw matches in green color
                   singlePointColor = None,
                   matchesMask = matchesMask, # draw only inliers
                   flags = 2)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp,img2,kp1,good,None,**draw_params)

plt.imshow(img3, 'gray'),plt.show()
#im1Reg=cv2.resize(im1Reg,d)
plt.imshow(dst, 'gray'),plt.show()
```

[image: drawing of matching keypoints][image: after wrap prespective i get this]

Comment: If you need to blend the overlay (after fixing your key point issue), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444510/creating-a-linear-gradient-mask-using-opencv-or/58459999#58459999

Answer (score 2):

Your warpPerspective is working correctly, but you aren't getting enough keypoint matches for your warp to turn out like you want. Try using a different keypoint detector like Brisk, KAZE, or AKAZE, and different keypoint matchers, like Brute Force or K-Nearest Neighbors.

Comment: Thank u Aaron for the suggestion I tired with AKAZE KAZE ADN Brisk but I m getting same kind of results as mentioned in question.

Comment: It looks like the images that you are trying to stitch together are just to similar, and openCV can't get enough rich keypoints to perform the desired operation. I way you could get around this is by creating mask images, where you find keypoints, descriptors, filter matches, calculate homography etc, but once all those calculations have been found, you then pass those off to your original images to be stitching together.

Comment: Thanks Aaron ...I have a doubt I exactly didn't get u what u mean by creating mask images? Did u mean to say mask the images which I m trying to stictch, with some other image....

Comment: create two images that are the same width and height in pixels as your two images above, and find matches on those images with keypoints and descriptors. After that, find the homography matrix, but instead of stitching the two images that you created together, pass the calculations from the mask images to the actual images you are trying to stitch together, then it should work.

Comment: Araon I figured out that warp perspective won't work in my case...so can I get (x,y) from keypoints and then translate the one  image to another image overlap each other over a common region?

Comment: You could do that if you wanted to, but you might have to do some blending on the image boarders to make it look cleaner.