# OpenCV Mat arithmetic cause type exception

Tags: c#, opencv

I have a function that blends two Mats into a destination Mat with gradient transition (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58445127/1725836):

```cs
private static void BlendImages(Mat src1, Mat src2, Mat dest, int x, int smoothKernel = 11, int smoothSigma = 7)
{
    using (var scaledSrc1 = new Mat(dest.Size(), src1.Type()))
    using (var scaledSrc2 = new Mat(dest.Size(), src2.Type()))
    using (var mask = new Mat(dest.Size(), src2.Type()))
    {
        Cv2.Resize(src1, scaledSrc1, scaledSrc1.Size());
        Cv2.Resize(src2, scaledSrc2, scaledSrc2.Size());
        mask.SetTo(0);
        Cv2.Rectangle(mask, new Rect(0, 0, x, dest.Height), Scalar.White, -1);
        Cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, mask, new Size(smoothKernel, smoothKernel), smoothSigma);

        var alpha = mask / 255.0;

        var weightedSrc1 = scaledSrc1 * alpha;
        var weightedSrc2 = scaledSrc2 * (1 - alpha);

        var weightedSrc = weightedSrc1 + weightedSrc2; // Exception :(
        Cv2.ConvertScaleAbs(weightedSrc, dest);
    }
}
```

But I got an exception at `weightedSrc1 + weightedSrc2` that says:
`OpenCvSharp.OpenCVException: '(type == (((5) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) || type == (((6) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) || type == (((5) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((2)-1) << 3)) || type == (((6) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((2)-1) << 3)))`

[image: Error Screenshot]

I just know that this error refers to an issue with the Mats' type, but I don't know what **exactly** should be fixed.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: that assertion demands `CV_32FC1` or `CV_64FC1` or `CV_32FC2` or `CV_64FC2`

Comment: is your debugger broken? does this exception come from the ConvertScaleAbs call? or is this possibly some leftover "string" from another exception? -- which "opencv" for c# do you even use? -- nevermind, "opencvsharp".

Comment: The debugger isn't broken. It fails in the `+` operator

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an assertion failed.

The assertion demands that `type` be one of `CV_32FC1, CV_64FC1, CV_32FC2, CV_64FC2`.

The exception message is incomplete. Usually it also reports what file and line of OpenCV source code this assertion was placed in.

You claim this happens in a Mat addition. You should check the types and channel counts of your operands.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophRackwitz ! I edited the question and added a screenshot of the exception and the Mats types and dimensions. The dimensions look right, but the type is probably wrong. Not sure why `alpha` is not a float type. I will convert it and check again

Comment: But I need 3 channels (BGR frames), why does it require 1 or 2 channels?